# Show images in specific folder and open selected image

Tags: android, image, android-intent, imageview, directory

I want to create an activity When I open the activity it to show images in specific folder called "myfolder" and when I select image I need it to show it in an imageview.

The code I created is working but it is showing me all images in my device and when I select image it return to the app but doesn't show the image in the imageview

```
ImageView imageview1;

private static final int REQUEST_OPEN_RESULT_CODE = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

    imageview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/myfolder/");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_OPEN_RESULT_CODE);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData){
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_OPEN_RESULT_CODE && requestCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri uri = null;
        if(resultData != null){
            uri = resultData.getData();

            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(uri)
                    .into(imageview1);
        }
    }
}
private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return bitmap;
}
private GestureDetector gs = null;
```

Comment: `When I open the activity it to show images in specific folder called "myfolder"` There is no code such that your activity would display images.

Comment: `The code I created is working but it is showing me all images in my device`. But that is not done by your activity but by Android OS after your Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. You are setting a -wrong- uri for your folder but, wrong or rigth, that 'Data' uri has no effect.

Comment: `Show images in specific folder and open selected image`. You mean: `Select images from a specific folder and open selected image`.

Comment: `getBitmapFromUri()`. You are not using that function. If you use it then do you get a bitmap?

Comment: Thanks, I know when using  ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT  Android OS will  display files not my activity. However, can I display files in specific folder using Android OS?

Comment: I am new to Android and this is my first APP. So can you explain to me clearly using getBitmapFromUri().

Comment: No no specific folder possible. And if you have an uri somewhere you can try out your function. I see no problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to convert URI to Path**

```
   public static String getPathFromURI(Context context, Uri uri) {
      String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
      String result = null;

      CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
              context, 
        uri, proj, null, null, null);        
      Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

      if(cursor != null){
       int column_index = 
         cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       result = cursor.getString(column_index);
      }
      return result;  
}
```

**and set path inside glide**

may be work

Comment: Thank you. I am new to Android, could you explain to me how to set the path inside glide

Comment: Glide.with(this)
                    .load(yourPath)
                    .into(imageview1);